# Is it permissible not to smile because of my teeth?

Tags: sunnah, adab

I'm aware it's a Sunnah and a charity but I'm shy to smile because my natural colour of my teeth is not white but a little yellowly white of the front six and bottom six in particular. I'm aware of all the oral hygiene habits in the modern world and the Sunnah acts (like using miswaak) and go to my dentist and hygienist regularly for a scale and polish to remove stains and tartar.

I don't like to smile with my teeth showing and smiling hiding my teeth can look fake. I'm also shy, reserved and quieter because I tend not to speak too much as I don't like to talk as the person listening will see my teeth! So you won't find me in photos as I don't like to be in them.

My dentist says people's teeth are not always white and I'm aware of so-called whitening toothpaste and bleaching etc but haven't had much luck. The hygienist says the whitening toothpaste only remove extrinsic stains but he uses a polishing paste which is more abrasive.

I don't smoke but tea coffee is prone to staining my teeth more than any other person. I know people who have white teeth but smoke and drink lots of black coffee! People say I'm over paranoid about them and they aren't bad but I would like them whiter!

Comment: Salam , Brother Bismillah--Ar-Rahaman-Ar-Raheem It is ok it is human nature but give more importance to Allah and keep in mind , it is from Allah and Allah love as you are

Comment: Can we be clearer on what it means to be "okay" not to smile?  Is the question asking if it's permissible not to smile?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is Sunnah and not doing so could limit you from gaining some easy (for me, at least) good deeds but Allah doesn't limit you to just smile.

> Abu Dharr narrated that the Prophet (SAW) said:
>   ""**Your smiling in the face of your brother is charity,** commanding good and forbidding evil is charity, your giving directions to a man lost in the land is charity for you. Your seeing for a man with bad sight is a charity for you, your removal of a rock, a thorn or a bone from the road is charity for you. Your pouring what remains from your bucket into the bucket of your brother is charity for you." ( Jami` at-Tirmidhi 1956 )

If it causes you discomfort to do charity in this form, Allah has given you many other ways to do so. Never despair in the mercy of Allah.

Sidenote: A key thing to remember is to always be grateful to Allah. Smile as you wish, but try not be ashamed or ungrateful for what Allah has given you. There are many Allah has not blessed with teeth.

And Allah knows best.